# Read&Write an opened excel file in C# while it is being edited

Tags: c#, excel, file, unity-game-engine

Good morning!

I have been struggling with a problem for a few weeks and when it seemed that the worst part was solved, now I have a problem with an Excel file.

What I want to do is to read and write an Excel file (Test.xls) by a program (Datahub), and at the same time, read and write the same Excel file by Unity3d using a C# script. I am using Bytescout Spreadsheet in C# to read/write from Excel. I have:

-Cells with references from Datahub, which values are being updated constantly. These values need to be read by Unity3d using C#

-Cells with values written by Unity3d using C#, which values are being read constantly by Datahub

Datahub needs the excel file to be opened in order to read/write but on the other hand, Unity3d through C# needs the file to be closed.

I have tried with a macro in the excel file to autosave it and in C# open the file and close it each time it reads/writes, but it does not work. I also tried to autosave it as a copy and in C# open that copy but it does not work either.

Would you know how to face this problem? Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: You could open the file with FileShare.ReadWrite in both programs, but that doesn't guarantee that they can both write to the file without causing corruption. Excel files aren't databases

Comment: Why would you not use a database instead of trying to imitate a database with an excel document?

Comment: You are right @PanagiotisKanavos and Adam Wilson , we were investigating database connection but at the same time we wanted to explore furtherly the excel option. I tried with FileShare.ReadWrite and although Unity could read from Datahub, the other way round does not seem to work. So yes, we are going to try with a database. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

If you using [ByteScout Spreadsheet SDK](https://bytescout.com/products/developer/spreadsheetsdk/bytescoutspreadsheetsdk.html) API then you may use your Excel file as the in-memory database to store values and recalculating other cells like this:

```
private void ReCalculate()
{
Worksheet worksheet;

worksheet = _spreadsheet.Workbook.Worksheets[0];

worksheet.Cell("A2").Value = System.Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
worksheet.Cell("B2").Value = System.Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text);
worksheet.Cell("C2").Formula = TextBox3.Text;
worksheet.Cell("C2").Calculate();
TextBox4.Text = worksheet.Cell("C2").Value.ToString();
}
```

This way serves well if you already have the spreadsheet with some data and formulas inside cells.

But if you are looking to just have a good way to store and retrive data then you should be better use database as it provides a scalable and reliable way to store large amounts of data (millions of rows), run queries and actually you may 2 or more simultenious connections! Databases are able to provide higher speed because of their internal design (indexes etc) while spreadsheets are better optimized to store data.

XLS, XSLX, CSV and other files are better suited for data export and data import to/from databases.

*Disclosure: I'm affiliated with ByteScout*

Comment: Thanks a lot for the idea!
I totally agree with you, now we are working in the implementation of Microsoft SQL Server 2014 and at the moment we got the connection between Datahub and the database. Now I'm working in the connection between Unity3D and the database and et voila! It's gonna be done finally :D